# Adding a sorting functionality in Node & ejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

I have a template that I run through some data coming from a local JSON File.

```
<tbody>
    <% data.t_upcoming.forEach((record) => { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=record.date%>
          <span style="display: block;font-size:10pt;"><%=record.time%></span>
          <p class="timer" style="font-size: 8pt; color: red;"></p>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="image" class="web_camera" src="/img/camera.png">
      </td>

      <td><a style="color:black;" href='/course-description'><%=record.course%></a>

        <span style="display:block;font-size:10pt;"><%=record.course_type%></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <% record.student.forEach((person) => { %>
          <img rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<%=person.name%>" src="<%=person.image%>">
        <% }) %>
      </td>

      <td>Recieved
        <span style="display:block; font-size: 16pt; color:#7c0000;"><%=record.status%></span>
      </td>

      <td>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MessageModal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send Message" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/message.png"></img></button>
        <button rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add Course" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/plus-course-record.png"></img></button>
        <a href='/student_grading' rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Grading & Feedback"  class="record_icons"><img src="/img/nike.png"></img></a>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChangeModal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Change Course" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/change.png"></img></button>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelModal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel Course" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/x.png"></img></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
```

Here is my Json File for reference

```
{
  "t_upcoming": [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "April 24, 2018 14:53:25",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Oil Painting",
    "course_type": "(Individual)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ],
    "completion": "Completed"
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "date": "April 23, 2018 16:37:25",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Art",
    "course_type": "(Group)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ],
    "completion": "Completed"
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "date": "April 22, 2018 15:37:25",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Algebra",
    "course_type": "(Group)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ],
    "completion": "Completed"
  }]
}
```

Now I want to add extra functionality to this table I have. I want to be able to either sort by the date or sort by the course.

```
<select>
    <option selected>Sort</option>
    <option>Date</option>
    <option>Course</option>
</select>
```

This is where I end up being a little stuck. How would I add the select dropdowns for dates and courses without having to render a new page? Currently I just cycle through each piece of data and print them in the order of how the table looks but I want to be able to sort not only by a date but also to the course.

Comment: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) `data.t_upcoming.sort((a,b) => {/* your sort algorithm */}).forEach`

Comment: So I would have to create a seperate partial for the table that contains this logic when Date or Course is selected right?

Comment: Otherwise you have to use `res.query`, and in your backend you have to handle your query and manipulate your array.